# Has any methodological research begun with a CrossValidated question?

Tags: discussion

Are there any publications that were motivated by a CrossValidated post? Was the site acknowledged? Is there a badge for that?

Comment: Not sure about methodological research. Another point is that CV is quite young for any paper to have made it through a publication cycle. Also, for the most part, the questions here are usually not research level, even in applications, as far as I can tell. There are some questions and answers here or there that have likely gotten someone over a hump (or at least out of a trough) on some of their work.

Comment: I think it would be good if someone could write up a paper describing the site, which people who want to acknowledge/thank the site could then reference. Biostar has done something like this.

Answer (score 16):

I thought that the answers to the question "[For which distributions are the parameterizations in BUGS and R different?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5543/1381)" would be of general interest to the R community so I wrote it up (in collaboration with the answer's author). The article "[Translating Probability Density Functions: From R to BUGS and Back Again.](http://people.bu.edu/dietze/manuscripts/lebauer-dietze-bolker.pdf)" is methodological, though the research part was limited to compiling references.

The acknowledgements read "This collaboration began on the Cross Validated statistical forum (http.//stats.stackexchange.com/q/5543/1381)."

Answer (score 14):

**Yes.**

Our paper summarizing this discussion: [Is ridge regression useless in high dimensions ($n \ll p$)? How can OLS fail to overfit?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328630) has just been published by *The Journal of Machine Learning Research*:

> The Optimal Ridge Penalty for Real-world High-dimensional Data Can Be Zero or Negative due to the Implicit Ridge Regularization
> *Dmitry Kobak, Jonathan Lomond, Benoit Sanchez; 21(169):1−16, 2020.*
> https://jmlr.org/papers/v21/19-844.html

It was a preprint since mid-2018: https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10939 but took some time to publish formally (and got substantially extended over the course of revisions). JMLR is a very respectable journal, so I am happy :-)

We of course acknowledge CrossValidated:

[image]

@amoeba, @JonnyLomond, @BenoitSanchez

Comment: Very respectable indeed!  They get the first opportunity to reject all my papers.

Comment: I forgot to say, congratulations!

Answer (score 13):

Hopefully there will be at some point. I am performing an empirical study of Nelder-Mead simplex, gradient descent and grid-search methods for model selection for kernel machines, which was inspired by a question on [Cross Validated](http://crossvalidated.com) (which appropriately is also the model selection criterion ;o).  No paper yet though.

Comment: The paper is currently in review.

Comment: Has this paper been published by now?

Comment: No, it was rejected (despite statistically significant result ;o), am still working on the second draft, hopefully it will be a better paper for the revisions.

Comment: Did you ever get this published?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have had some issues in real life that have limited my research activity (and a huge teaching load!)  It is quite difficult to get rigorous studies of things that make minor, but worthwhile improvements to best practice.  Especially frustrating as what I was suggesting is *less* computationally expensive!

Answer (score 11):

Almost two years after having asked this question, I actually wrote a paper inspired by CV (still unpublished):

http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4920

I used the question's url in the body of the text.

Comment: John could you correct the name of the site in the title and body of your post here (you're missing a "d") and *also* in your paper (replace the terminal "s" with a "d")?

Comment: Thank you. I edited this post. Could you be more specific about the changes needed in the paper?

Comment: In the abstract, fix the name of the site - i.e. the same word as you corrected here. That is, taking the abstract from [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4920): "*in the statistics Questions & Answers web site Cross Validates*", replace the terminal *s* with a *d*. You could just search for 'cross'.

Comment: This issue (that the summary at the link refers to our site as "Cross Validates") remains.

Answer (score 10):

A badge for it would be tricky, as it's not an automatic thing that can be scraped from the site itself.

I don't know of any methods research spawned by CV, but I haven't been here all that long, so someone may come and chime in. I have however used it to sanity check an idea or two that I've had. Though the one time CV did out-and-out answer the question, I had a better source provided.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently looking into the class imbalance problem, which is a very common methodological issue on this site, and have been working on a tutorial paper.  The lack of an answer to my question ["How do you know that your classifier is suffering from class imbalance?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539638/how-do-you-know-that-your-classifier-is-suffering-from-class-imbalance) suggests there are some issues with current practice that need to be addressed.  Cross Validatated seems a good place for finding out what people actually do (or don't do)